# About Integrals in the book "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, exponential-function

The book "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik contains the following two integrals : ( 7th edition section 3.481 ):

1. $$\int_{-∞}^∞ xe^x \exp (−μe^x)\,dx =\frac{−1}{μ }(C + \ln μ)$$
2. $$\int_{-∞}^∞ xe^x \exp (−μe^{2x})\,dx =\frac{−1}{μ} [C+\ln(4μ)]\sqrt{π/μ} $$

$C$ is Euler's constant

For $[\operatorname{Re} μ > 0]$

I want to generalize these type of integrals to :

$$I(n;t) = \int_t^∞ x^n e^{μ_1x} \exp (−μ_2e^{2x}) \, dx $$

For cases : $ t=0, -\infty$

> > Question : How to evaluate $I(n;t)$ for a closed form?

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t=-\infty$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{ + \infty } {x^n e^{\mu _1 x} \exp ( - \mu _2 e^{2x} )dx}  = \frac{1}{{2^{n + 1} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {(\log t)^n t^{\mu _1 /2 - 1} \exp ( - \mu _2 t)dt} .
$$
But since
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{z/2 - 1} \exp ( - wt)dt}  = \frac{{\Gamma (z/2)}}{{w^{z/2} }},
$$
one has
$$
\frac{1}{{2^n }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {(\log t)^n t^{z/2 - 1} \exp ( - wt)dt}  = \frac{{d^n }}{{dz^n }}\frac{{\Gamma (z/2)}}{{w^{z/2} }}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{ + \infty } {x^n e^{\mu _1 x} \exp ( - \mu _2 e^{2x} )dx}  = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{{d^n }}{{dz^n }}\frac{{\Gamma (z /2)}}{{\mu _2^{z /2} }}\right]_{z=\mu_1}.
$$
You may expand the right-hand side via the Leibniz formula.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Gary also ,  please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3532996/702232